# How do I make sure the correct answer choices are displayed within a quiz app?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am developing a quiz app where I have a constant array of questions and answers. The answer choices are associated with the questions by having the same index as its corresponding question (For example the the first answer choices in the answers array go with the first index of the questions array and so on). However I am randomizing the selection of the question that is asked from the questions array so but the corresponding answers are not appearing with the right question that is shown. What is best way to go about having the right answer choices appear with the question that is randomly selected and shown? Also how would I prevent a question that has already been answered to not be randomly selected again until the quiz has failed and has been reset? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit 

class ViewController:UIViewController {
    //random question generation function
    func randomQuestion() {
        index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
        questionLabel.text = questions[index]
    }

    //costants
    let questions = ["Who is Thor's half brother?", "What is the name of Thor's hammer?"]
    var answers = [["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"], ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Odin's Staff"]]

    //variables
    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerBox:UInt32 = 0
    var index = 0

    //Question Label
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    //Answer Button
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox)) {
            print ("Correct!")
        } else {
            wrongSeg()
            print ("Wrong!")
        }

        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        newQuestion()
    }

    //function that displays new question
    func newQuestion()
    {
        //countdown timer section
        randomQuestion()

        rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

        //create a button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        var x = 1

        for index in 1...4
        {
            //creat a button
            button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

            if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
            {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][0], for: .normal)
            } else {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)
                x += 1
            }
        }

        currentQuestion += 1
        randomImage()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a more appropriate data structure.

Something like:

```
class Question {
    var id: Int
    var questionText: String
    var answers: [String]
    var answered = false
}
```

You then randomize the Question array. You keep track of the index that you are on and move forward in the array until it ends.

At the end of the loop, check to see which questions haven't been answered, remove the answered ones (or create a new array) and repeat the process.

You can enumerate through the array

```
var questions = [Question]()

//populate the array

    for (index, question) in questions.enumerated() {
        //This returns the question as well as the current index
    }
```

Comment: How would I keep track of the index to make sure a question isn't repeated after it has already been answered?

Comment: you can remove them from the array, then traverse the new array. Or you can mark them as answered and ignore them in your random selection.

Comment: Also, I edited the question to using a Class instead of a Struct because it makes it easier to manipulate classes in an array.

Comment: Thank you for you help! How in code would I move from array though, could you give an example please? You've been really insightful!

Comment: besides enumeration, you could just keep a reference to an index in the class itself. var currentIndex = 0;

Comment: Still how could I pair the answers with the questions to make sure the correct questions show up with the corresponding answer choices? Right now my code shows a random set of answers with a random question, not the right pairing of answers and questions

Answer (score 1):

**1. Make a struct**

This allows a question and an array of answers to be packaged, useful when shuffling later.

```
struct Question {
    var id: Int
    var questionText: String
    var answers: [String]
}

var example = Question(id: 1, questionText: "Foo?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"])
var id = example.id
var questionText = example.questionText
var answers = example.answers
```

**2. Now randomize an array of Questions using the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)**

Cool because O(n) time.

```
var question1 = Question(id: 1, questionText: "Foo?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"])
var question2 = Question(id: 2, questionText: "Bar?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"])
var question3 = Question(id: 3, questionText: "Baz?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"])
var question4 = Question(id: 4, questionText: "What is after Baz?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"])

var questions = [question1, question2, question3, question4]

for i in 0..<questions.count-2 {
    var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(questions.count - i))
    var copy = questions[i]
    questions[i] = questions[rand]
    questions[rand] = copy
}

print(questions)    // shuffled
```

Comment: This seems like a successful way to handle this problem but my app contains over 600 questions so I don't think making 600+ variables labeled "question" would be the most efficient way.